# MongoDB: Unique Key in Embedded Document

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to set a unique key for a key in an embedded document?

I have a Users collection with the following sample documents:

```
 {
       Name: "Bob",
       Items: [
           {
               Name: "Milk"
           },
           {
               Name: "Bread"
           }
       ]
    },
    {
       Name: "Jim"
    },
```

Is there a way to create an index on the property Items.Name?

I got the following error when I tried to create an index:

```
> db.Users.ensureIndex({"Items.Name": 1}, {unique:true});
E11000 duplicate key error index: GroceryGuruApp.Users.$Items.Name_1  dup key: {
 : null }
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unique indexes exist only across collection. To enforce uniqueness and other constraints across document you must do it in client code. (Probably [virtual collections](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142) would allow that, you could vote for it.)

What are you trying to do in your case is to create index on key `Items.Name` which doesn't exist in any of the documents (it doesn't refer to embedded documents inside array `Items`), thus it's `null` and violates unique constraint across collection.

Comment: Thanks. It does seems like enforcing this in the client-side seems to be the only option so far.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up having to query for the object, check for duplicates in the client-side, and then using the $set operator on the Items array

Comment: @Abe: Are you using `findAndModify` for this, or are your operation split in two parts, a query and an update? If split, how do you deal with the atomicity of the operations?

Answer (score 11):

You can create a **unique compound sparse index** to accomplish something like what you are hoping for. It may not be the best option (client side still might be better), but it can do what you're asking depending on specific requirements.

To do it, you'll need to create another field on the same level as `Name: Bob` that is unique to each top-level record (could do FirstName + LastName + Address, we'll call this key `Identifier`).

Then create an index like this:

```
ensureIndex({'Identifier':1, 'Items.name':1},{'unique':1, 'sparse':1})
```

A sparse index will ignore items that don't have the field, so that should get around your `NULL` key issue. Combining your unique Identifier and `Items.name` as a compound unique index should ensure that you can't have the same item name twice per person.

Although I should add that I've only been working with Mongo for a couple of months and my science could be off. This is not based on empirical evidence but rather observed behavior.

#### More on MongoDB Indexes

- [Compound Keys Indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeysIndexes)
- [Sparse Indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-SparseIndexes)

Comment: It won't work as of Mongo 2.2. Unique index ensures uniqueness across documents and not subdocuments, therefore unique `Identifier` makes this suggestion completely unuseful (since `Identifier` unique for each document, whole `Identifier` + `Items.name` always unique too). More details [here](http://joegornick.com/2012/10/25/mongodb-unique-indexes-on-single-embedded-documents/).

Answer (score 3):

The index will be across all Users and since you asked it for 'unique', no user will be able to have two of the same named item AND no two users will be able to have the same named Item.

Is that what you want?

Furthermore, it appears that it's objecting to two Users having a 'null' value for Items.Name, clearly Jim does, is there another record like that?

It would be unusual to require uniqueness on an indexed collection like this.

MongoDB does allow unique indexes where it indexes only the first of each value, see 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-DuplicateValues, but I suspect the real solution is to not require uniqueness in this case.

If you want to ensure uniqueness only within the Items for a single user you might want to try the $addToSet option.  See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSet

Comment: Yes, that's a great point. It does seem like my definition of unique would be I can't have duplicate item names for a given user document. Basically, I just want to not allow duplicates for a given property within an embedded document.

Comment: You can use $addToSet to update the Items collection.  See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSet

Comment: Unfortunately, $addToSet does not work on an array of embedded documents. I tried doing that, but the duplicate items still get added, at least in Mongo 1.6.5

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to model the items as a hash with the item name as the key.

```
Items: { "Milk": 1, "Bread": 1 }
```

I'm not sure about whether you're trying to use the index for performance or purely for the constraint. The right way to approach depends on your use cases, and determining whether the atomic operations are enough to keep your data consistent.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually a really good workaround to eliminate duplicates. The only issue I see is that I am using a ASP.NET 3.5/C# and that would be difficult to model without using a dictionary. The list of items in my cases would change frequently.

Comment: You could make it a dictionary with the value as Item objects instead of just the 1s I have there if you wanted. But yeah, it's a dictionary, and can't really be mapped to a nested entity (if that's what you're referring to with the ASP.NET/C#) since it's keys will vary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use findAndModify to create a sequence/counter function.

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: name },
        update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        new: true,
        upsert: true
    });
    return ret.seq;
}
```

Then use it whenever a new id is needed...

```
db.users.insert({
    _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
    name: "Sarah C."
})
```

This is from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/.  Check it out.