# Nested object schema in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's suppose I have a schema like this

```
var Language = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    pos: [{
        name: String,
        attributes: [{
            name: String
        }]
    }]
});
```

Will each item in `pos`, and in `attributes`, have an `_id`? If I add a unique index to the `name` field in the `pos` array, will uniqueness be enforced to just that array, or will it be unique for all entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, embedded documents like `pos` and `attributes` that don't have their own schema do not have an `_id` property.

If you add a unique index to the `name` field in the `pos` array, uniqueness will be enforced across the collection, but **not** within the array of a single document.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743849/mongodb-unique-index-on-array-elements-property).

Comment: This is not correct as of Mongoose 4, where `pos` and `attributes` will get their own schema.

Answer (score 1):

In Mongoose 4, `pos` and `attributes` will get their own schema. You can prevent them from getting _id attributes like so:

```
// ...
    attributes: [{
        name: String,
        _id: false
    }]
// ...
```