# MongoDB: deleting duplicate documents with arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, duplicates

I'm trying to remove all duplicates in a collection with ensureIndex and dropDups, but this method doesn't seem to work with arrays.
For example, if I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54d8f889e3fdfe0cd8b769ed"), "field1" : "a", "field2" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54d8f89be3fdfe0cd8b769ee"), "field1" : "a", "field2" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54d8f8a3e3fdfe0cd8b769ef"), "field1" : "a", "field2" : [ "a", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54d8f8abe3fdfe0cd8b769f0"), "field1" : "a", "field2" : [ "b", "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54d8f8c5e3fdfe0cd8b769f1"), "field1" : "b", "field2" : [ "a", "b" ] }
```

and use ensureIndex like this:

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({field1: 1, field2: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

the result would be:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54d8f89be3fdfe0cd8b769ee"), "field1" : "a", "field2" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54d8f8c5e3fdfe0cd8b769f1"), "field1" : "b", "field2" : [ "a", "b" ] }
```

Is there a way to do this so that only exact Duplicates (in my example collection only the first or second entry) get deleted?

Comment: No, because indexes on arrays are [multikey](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/). You can use an aggregation to identify duplicate documents or update each document with a field whose value is based on `field1` and `field2` and then create a unique index with `dropDups` on that field.

Answer (score 0):

As I know this feature doesn't work in arrays. Any particular reason why you can't just use **$addToSet** when you insert the data?

Check this question, maybe help you [MongoDB: Unique index on array element's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743849/mongodb-unique-index-on-array-elements-property)

Comment: well, I'm trying to clean up an existing e-mail dataset

Comment: also, $addToSet only prevents duplicates in arrays, I want to prevent duplicate documents that may contain arrays as fields

Comment: Ok, I see that you use default ObjectId.  You can try to compose custom "_id" from fields "field1" and "field2".  Create a function that given a field and array return a string compose of these two and assign as "_id". If there are duplicates will throw an excepction.