# Mongodb ensure one array field unique

Tags: arrays, mongodb, unique

I am trying to make email as unique. I tried using 'unique' and 'dropDups', but it doesn't work. Any idea what I should use?

```
var custSchema = new Schema({ 
  "username": String,
  "Password": String,
  "email": {["Type": String,
             "Value": { type : String, lowercase: true, unique: true, dropDups: true}]
})
```

Example of csv data:

```
        username       Password            Email
                                      Type     Value
User1:   test1        asdub**jhas    Primary   test1@user1.com
User2:   test2        3kjnn**8man    Primary   Pract@test.com
User3:   test3        dsffs**as97    Primary   test1@user1.com
```

In this example case, there would be only two users added to the database: User1 and User2, because User3 has the same email address as User1.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Index for `email.Value` with option `unique: true` and this will help us in preventing the insert of duplicate values for email Id.

```
db.collection_name.createIndex({"email.Value":1}, {unique:true})
```

References:

[CreateIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)

[Another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982324/array-with-unique-values-over-all-documents-of-one-collection)

Comment: i put this one in my Schema.js, but it complains about not finding 'db'.

Comment: This syntax is for Mongodb shell, you have to modify the query so that it suits your programming language

Answer (score 0):

There might be some other solution that can fix this. But after I tried defining 'Email' as

```
"Email": [
{"Type": String,
  "Value": { type : String, lowercase: true, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}}
}]
```

it works fine.

Comment: Yours and mine are the same approach ie, having unique index.