# Make an Array of unique elements in c# mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

How can I create an array of unique elements in MongoDB c# driver,

I don't want to check every time if this element already in the array or not.

suppose :

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
```

then I shouldn't be able to add duplicate element (such as `3` )

Comment: I assume you are referring to uniqueness on insert?  If so, check out a unique index option.

Comment: i expect uniqueness on insert and update. how to create unique index on array elements in MongoDB c# driver

Comment: HI @akash - the index is created on the database.  I suspect you could issue a command via c# driver, but then again creating indexes is not something typically done more than once.  With that in mind you probably would find it easier to create an index using the mongo shell.  Here is the docs... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

Comment: @barrypicker -if i create an index on database, then i think  array will be unique not the elements in array.

Comment: This post should give you a head start https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052168/1859959. I mean the "BUT if you strictly use $addToSet with the index" part

Comment: @akash - yes, you are correct.  Please disregard my advice to use a unique index on arrays.  Unique Multi-key indexes ensure selectivity of the parent document, not the elements in array embedded in the document.  Sorry for the misdirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AddToSet` or `AddToSetEach` method, every time you create or update the array, as mentioned in the comments:

```
var update = Builders<Entity>.Update.AddToSetEach(e => e.Items, new [] {1, 2});
collection.UpdateOne(new BsonDocument(), update, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

And you can define a [schema validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) when creating the collection, to ensure that duplicate items will never be allowed (an error would be thrown on insert/update, “Document failed validation”).

You can define the schema  in the MongoDB shell, or here is how to do it in C#:

```
var options = new CreateCollectionOptions<Entity>
{
    ValidationAction = DocumentValidationAction.Error,
    ValidationLevel = DocumentValidationLevel.Strict,
    Validator = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Entity>().JsonSchema(new BsonDocument
    {
        { "bsonType", "object" },
        { "properties", new BsonDocument("Items", new BsonDocument
            {
                { "type" , "array" },
                { "uniqueItems", true }
            })
        }
    })
};

database.CreateCollection("entities", options, CancellationToken.None);
```

where `Entity` is an example class like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public int[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the [API docs for CreateCollectionOptions](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_CreateCollectionOptions_1.htm) and in the unit tests you can see [examples of usage - e.g. JsonSchema()](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/6f748612f89cbce37c5446301d0f7858e333877e/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/FilterDefinitionBuilderTests.cs#L546). Unfortunately I don't see anything in the reference docs with more thorough explanations.

Comment: Can you share the link of  mongodb c# driver validation schema docs??

Comment: Added link - the unit tests seem to be the best docs available