# MongoDB error E11000 duplicate key error collection due to empty array containing document with email null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

### This is the code I am writing:

```
      const createOrgPerso= new Person({
        org: newOrganisation._doc.id,
        // data: [],
      });
```

But the empty array is still getting created. And then this code is run again, it gives `E 11000 duplicate key error collection: managerhq.studentdatas index: data.email_l dup key: { data.email: null }` error

[image]

### Problem description :

I think this is because I have set `required: true` for some fields.

### What I want is:

Just create a document with the `org` field only. I will fill the data array with documents later.
My goal is: same email(also few other fields) cannot be repeated in the `data` array

### This is the mongoose schema

[image]

The indexes in that collection
[image]

If any more details is required, please tell in comments.

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. As for your problem: You don't show the index definiton on `data` so nobody knows, how this index looks like. But it problably forbids two objects with having an empty data array or a missing data array ...

Comment: And creating a lot of objects and only adding a value that should be unique later on may be a bad idea, because you may end up in a situation, where you cannot assign a value to an already existing element because of an index violation ... You may want to rethink that design ...

Comment: added the index of the collection to the question now. Please check once

Comment: It seems like your index is not on the elements in the `data` array but on the property `data.email`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Unique index on array element's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743849/mongodb-unique-index-on-array-elements-property)

Comment: Problem is happen when creating a document... not when pushing to the array.
When I am creating the document without the `data:[]`, still the data filed is getting created. I don't want data to be created

Comment: Yeah, but probably only on the second element, because there is already an element with `data.email === undefined` existing. And still, even if the index was working correctly (ie allowing elements with `data === []` you can create three elements with `data =[]` and then when inserting the email, you can run into problems and have elements in you database where you cannot set the email. What to do with such elements?

Answer (score 2):

Try

1. removing the `index:true`
   or
2. removing the `unique:true` fields from the Schema (rely on different method of validation of duplicate items)

Answer (score 1):

Your ORM, Mongoose, creates an empty array when you save a new instance. Mongo considers `undefined/null` *a unique value* so you can't have two instances that have an empty `data` array as that would cause `data.email` to be `undefined/null` in the second document as well.

Setting `data` to be `undefined`, rather than `[]` should remedy that.

As [mentioned by vkarpov15 on Sequelize's issue tracker](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4185#issuecomment-223152265):

> If you have an array in your schema, mongoose will create an empty array `[]` for you by default so you can do `.push()` and such without explicitly creating the array. To shut this off, overwrite the default array default
>
> ```
> var schema = new Schema({
>  myArr: { type: [String], default: undefined }
> });
> ```