# UniqueIndex doesn't work in the EmbeddedDocument

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I see that the constraint UniqueIndex is ignored within the embedded document, here's an example :

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument()
 */

class Service
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id()
     */

    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field("type=string")
     * @MongoDB\UniqueIndex()
     */
    protected $label;
...
```

When I insert 2 rows with same label, they are accepted, when I need to get the code exception 11000 concerning the duplicate key error.
Any solutions ?

**Keyswords** :

- Symfony 3.2
- ODM 1.1.5
- MongoDB 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Question answered already: [MongoDB: Unique Key in Embedded Document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4437836/5258328)

> Unique indexes exist only across collection. To enforce uniqueness and other constraints across document you must do it in client code. (Probably [virtual collections](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142) would allow that, you could vote for it.)

Comment: J'ai vu cette réponse, juste je voudrais savoir s'il y a des solutions en PHP plus claire, en tout cas merci

Comment: You can do it simply by adding some restrictions on your AddService(Service $service) method, so that you can call on it all the existed services (getServices()) and foreach service check the name is already existed or not, if existed, then throw exception.

Comment: Yeah , that's what I did already ... just the standard way :) , thank you !!

Comment: @MohamedRadhiGuennichi Please flag a question as a duplicate instead of posting the answer with a link to original post.